# Posts used for review audits in the Low Quality Posts queue should not always be good posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits, low-quality-posts

One of the purposes of review audits is to stop robo-reviewers. For the Low Quality Posts queue, I never had an audit where "Recommend Deletion" or "Recommend Close" was the right action. For the audits, "Looks Good" was *always* the right action. Robo-reviewers will, most likely, just click on the "Looks Good" button without looking at the post, so they will **never** fail a Low Quality Posts audit, because there are always good posts picked for the audits.

So, my suggestion is: also pick bad posts for the Low Quality Posts audits, where "Recommend Deletion" or "Recommend Close" is the correct action.

Comment: I think the OP is right, although I'm not 100% sure for the low quality posts. I do know that this type of issue is the Same with the "Suggested Edits Review Queue". The only audit ones seem to be "rejecting this edit was the right choice". They are never "accepting this edit was the right choice".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was supposed to already be happening, however a bug was introduced that ensured no eligible "known-bad" audits would ever be selected.

Thanks for reporting this.

Comment: What was the bug?

Comment: There's a query that's supposed to look for deleted posts that have validated spam flags on them. Instead, it looks for deleted posts that have *live* spam flags on them. A live (active/unhandled) spam flag on a deleted post is a situation that shouldn't ever be allowed, and as a result generally doesn't exist.

Comment: Fixed in next build